# How to implement a smart response cache depending on the error in the response?

Tags: alamofire

Good afternoon, Everyone!

I'm trying to make sure that the cache is used only for the scenario when I get an error in the response (not any error). Take data from the cache only if there is no Internet or did not wait for a response, but only for GET requests.

Below I tried to make an example that works, but it seems to me that this logic can be made more correct and more beautiful. Please tell me what you should pay attention to or where you can read about such a solution?

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel: ViewModel = .init()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Reload", action: self.viewModel.onLoad)
            ScrollView {
                Text(self.viewModel.result)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
            }
        }
    }
}
extension ContentView {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        typealias ResponseInfo = (HTTPURLResponse?, Result<Data?, AFError>)
        @Published private(set) var result: String = ""
        private let session: Alamofire.Session
        private let cacheResponse: URLCache
        //
        init() {
            self.session = .init(
                configuration: .default,
                requestQueue: .init(label: "Queue by Alamofire Session")
            )
            self.cacheResponse = {
                let cachesURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
                let diskCacheURL = cachesURL.appendingPathComponent("DownloadCache")
                return .init(memoryCapacity: 10_000_000, diskCapacity: 1_000_000_000, directory: diskCacheURL)
            }()
        }
        func onLoad() {
            self.result = ""
            self.runRequest(
                url: "https://google.com",
                handleResponse: { [weak self] (response, result) in
                    self?.result = {
                        var resultText: String = ""
                        resultText += "Date: \(response?.headers.first(where: { $0.name == "Date" })?.value ?? "")"
                        resultText += "\n"
                        resultText += "Response:"
                        resultText += "\n"
                        do {
                            if let data = try result.get() {
                                resultText += .init(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                                                ?? .init(data: data, encoding: .ascii)
                                                ?? .init(reflecting: data)
                            }
                        }
                        catch {
                            resultText += .init(reflecting: error)
                        }
                        return resultText
                    }()
                }
            )
        }
        private func runRequest(url: String, handleResponse: @escaping (ResponseInfo) -> Void) {
            let completionHandler = { [weak self] (responseData: AFDataResponse<Data?>) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    guard let self = self else {
                        return
                    }
                    let resultData = responseData.result
                    // MARK: Check Request is GET
                    if let request = responseData.request, request.method == .get {
                        // MARK: Check Error
                        switch resultData {
                        case .success:
                            // MARK: Save Cache
                            if let response = responseData.response {
                                let dataResponse = responseData.data ?? .init()
                                self.cacheResponse.storeCachedResponse(
                                    .init(
                                        response: response,
                                        data: dataResponse,
                                        userInfo: [ "date": Date() ],
                                        storagePolicy: .allowed
                                    ),
                                    for: request
                                )
                            }
                            break
                        case .failure(let error):
                            if case .sessionTaskFailed(let errorSession) = error {
                                if let errorUrl = errorSession as? URLError {
                                    // MARK: Check Cache
                                    switch errorUrl.code {
                                    case .notConnectedToInternet, .timedOut:
                                        if let resultDataCache = self.cacheResponse.cachedResponse(for: request) {
                                            // MARK: Finish Success Cache
                                            return handleResponse(
                                                (
                                                    resultDataCache.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                                                    .success(resultDataCache.data)
                                                )
                                            )
                                        }
                                    default:
                                        break
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    // MARK: Finish Default
                    return handleResponse((responseData.response, resultData))
                }
            }
            // MARK: run Request
            self.session
                .request(url)
                .response(completionHandler: completionHandler)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe with https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondatadelegate/1411612-urlsession ? With Alamofire, I guess having a look at https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/CachedResponseHandler.swift might worth a try